# CAML Query not limiting rows

Tags: 2010, spservices

I'm using the SPServices GetListItems function to pull entries from a calendar list. All of the information is being retreived without any issues. However the RowLimit is not restricting the number of items being returned.

```
camlQuery = "<Query>"
                +"<CalendarDate>" + calendarDate + "</CalendarDate>
                +"<Where>"
                    +"<DateRangesOverlap>"
                        +"<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />"
                        +"<FieldRef Name='EndDate' />"
                        +"<FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />"
                        +"<Value Type='DateTime'>Month</Value>"
                    +"</DateRangesOverlap>"
                +"</Where>"
                +"<OrderBy>"
                    +"<FieldRef Name='EventDate' />"
                +"</OrderBy>"
                +"<RowLimit>6</RowLimit>"
            +"</Query>";
```

Comment: You need to make sure that the Web application associated with the site does not have a row limit more than what you expect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the SPServices library, you just need to add an option like this in your GetListItems configuration:

```
CAMLRowLimit: 6
```

Marc then tacks this onto the appropriate place in the dynamically built CAML query to get your data.

Answer (score 15):

Your `<RowLimit>` tag is inside `<Query>` tag which is wrong, it should be out side the `<Query>` and inside `<View>`.

Try below

```
camlQuery = "<View><Query><CalendarDate>" + calendarDate + "</CalendarDate><Where><DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' /><Value Type='DateTime'>Month</Value></DateRangesOverlap></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' /></OrderBy></Query><RowLimit>6</RowLimit></View>";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.RowLimit = 10;
SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
```

Comment: Love it when the simple answers work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this CAMLRowLimit,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert("ASD");
    var idquery="<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy></Query>";
        $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "test",
        CAMLQuery: idquery,
        CAMLRowLimit: 1,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        //alert($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
        var getvalue= parseInt($(this).attr("ows_Title"))+1;//Auto increment value
        $("input[title='TicketNumber']").val(getvalue);

    });
    }
    });


    <a href="http://peakfinders.blogspot.com/2015/10/how-to-get-id-of-last-inserted-row-in.html">more details</a>
```

Comment: Can you please add some description of your answer. Just code do not give a clue.