# Using SP Services to get data, Need only top 5

Tags: jquery, spservices

So, as the title suggests, i'm using SP Services to get data from the "Comments" List. I can retrieve the data fine but i'm trying to limit what is returned to only the top (Let's say 5) comments by submitted date. This is what I have

but the if statement doesn't work;

```
function getID2(valID) {

        var cmtotal = Number(valID.split('-')[1]);
        valID = Number(valID.split('-')[0]);

        if (cmtotal <= 0) {
            $('#cModal').modal('hide');
            return;
        } else {

            $("#txtin").html('');
            var EVENTID = Number(valID);
            var method = "GetListItems";
            var webURL = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite();
            var list = "Comments";
            var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" + "<FieldRef Name='Name' />" + "</ViewFields>";
            var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'  Descending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>";
            var i = 0;
            var max = 5;
            $().SPServices({
                operation: method,
                async: false,
                webURL: webURL,
                listName: list,
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
                CAMLQuery: query,
                completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                        if (i == max + 1) {
                            return;
                        } else {
                            var cID = Number($(this).attr("ows_EventID").split("#")[1]);
                            if (EVENTID == cID) {
                                var auth = $(this).attr("ows_Author").split("#")[1];
                                var body = $(this).attr("ows_Body");
                                $("#txtin").append(
                                    '<div class="container-fluid">' +
                                    '<div class="col-xs-2" style="text-align: right">' + auth + ':</div>' +
                                    '<div class="col-xs-10"><div class="well" style="text-align: left">' + body + '</div></div>' +
                                    '</div>'
                                );
                                i++;
                            }
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: Same question here. https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117550/caml-query-not-limiting-rows/117554

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is the scope of your variable "i" which you are incrementing inside the function which gets called on each row and gets its own copy of "i" each time.

Put an alert displaying "i" and you will see what I mean.

Why not use

```
 CAMLRowLimit: 5
```

In your SPServices call - it should do all that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can write your query like this:

```
var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID'  Descending='True' /></OrderBy><RowLimit>5</RowLimit></Query>";
```